# Access to related list in apex

Tags: apex, soql, record-type, related-list

I have a standard object Account and in this object Account I have four record types.
Two of the record types are "Partner" and "Partner Role".
In the "Partner" record type I have a related list "Partner Role".
In apex I'm using a SOQL query to take all Partner records and add them in a list.
I iterate over the list of Partners and for each Partner I need to get its "Partner Role" related list.

What I need to do in apex to access the related list in each Partner?

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
// return all accouts of type Partner
  List<Account> listOfPartners  = new List<Account>([SELECT id, Partner_Name__c, Partner_Roles__r.Company_Name__c FROM Account where RecordTypeId = '0120Z0000000yXz']);

  for (Account partner: listOfPartners) {    
      // How to get the related Partner_Roles__r list       
  }
```

In the above SOQL I get the following error message:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Partner_Roles__r' in field path. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the
>   '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL
>   or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? It's a little hard to understand what you mean based on your current description.

Comment: Go to that lookup and see what the child relationship name is

Comment: You cannot query like that. Account is a parent object of Partner Roles. Partner_Roles__r has no meaning in the query. Read through this article - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the child relation ship name is Account_Partner_roles. `Account` is the parent of `Partner Role` here. You can get the Partner role records of a Account of particular record type using :

```
List<Account> acc = [Select id, name, RecordType.Name,(select id,Name from Account_Partner_roles__r) 
FROM Account
WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('Partner');
```

You can iterate over the Account `list acc` and get all the related list.